# Storyboard gets rid of `customModuleProvider="target"` on XML and stops finding class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I am trying to debug a problem that is happening on my Xcode install that makes my Main Storyboard not find my custom classes. Steps to reproduce:

- Create a single view application
- Run the app without any modifications, ensuring everything still works as supposed
- Go to the main storyboard, click the yellow icon for the view controller, then focus the custom class input where `ViewController` is already filled. Hit enter.

When I do this, Xcode removes an attribute `customModuleProvider="target"` from the `viewController` node in my Storyboard, which causes the app to not find the custom class `ViewController` anymore.

How can I fix the project, allowing the Storyboard my classes again?

Comment: I can confirm that this removes `customModuleProvider=""` (which was empty for my case) in a new project. But I'm not sure what problems I should see. However https://bugreport.apple.com is probably the better place to report bugs. If the removal of the `customModuleProvider` attribute causes issues that's a bug in Xcode. And what's the question?

Comment: Alright, will do so.

Comment: BTW, I've added a more clearer question at the end of it.

Comment: When adding Swift UI classes to an existing Obj-C project, of my 3 Swift classes, IB set the "customModuleProvider" for only one automatically. So at runtime, only one custom class was instantiated, while the other two were silently replaced with instances of their base classes. Manually entering the target name in the "Module" field caused Xcode/IB to instantiate the correct swift classes. Apple alludes to this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_68

Comment: I've reinstalled Xcode and the issues have been solved.